# Creating a twitter bot got really difficult

Tags: twitter, bots

I followed step by step the way I could, the twitter's guide for developers but I wasn't able to connect

> errors: [
> {
> message: 'You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access
> via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve'

The aim of this bot is to get tweets of bands in my town to know when are they comming whitout checking every day.

I don't get where I have to apply for elevated access as it's said there.

Do I have to pay to do this proyect right away?
Do I have to be in an organization or enterprise to hace this access?

Comment: Probably part of Elon's plan to raise funds for Twitter, but putting a paywall in-front of things users actually want to use.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a twitter support question.

Comment: I also get this error.  Only on one account and not another.  Any fixes? There is no elevated access anymore.  Am I wrong?  Help!